# best practice: putting a section in pages header and giving it a heading

Tags: html

I have a rather complex website which is in need for redesign.

Using html5 features I started with a structure like this:

```
<body>
<header>...</header>
<main>
    <section>...</section>
    <section>...</section>
</main>
<footer>...</footer>
</body>
```

now starting to put some more content in the `<header>` like:

```
<header>
    <section id="hCart">
        <header>...</header>
    </section>
</header>
```

The validator starts to complain: *"The element header must not appear as a descendant of the header element."* Same goes for the `<footer>`.

So is it generally a bad idea to structure the `<body>` with `<header>` & `<footer>` sections? Or am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT:**

To make more sense:

- My website contains some `<section>`s in the page's `<header>` (one of them beeing a shopping cart)
- The spec allows for `<section>` in `<header>` but not to give them a `<header>` by their own.
- The second `<header>` is used for defining one of these `<section>`' heads.
- I know that I can't use `<header>` as descendant of `<header>` according to the spec. What I want to know is how am I supposed to do this in another way semantically correct?
- The problem is even bigger in the page's `<footer>` where I wannted to put multiple sections like `<section><header><img/><h1>external links</h1></header> ... </section>` and so on.

Comment: [From the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header): ***Permitted content:** Flow content, but with no <header> or <footer> descendant* and ***Permitted parent elements:** Any element that accepts flow content. Note that a <header> element must not be a descendant of an <address>, <footer> or another <header> element.*

Answer (score 2):

I would like to recommend you to take a look at [html5 doctor](http://html5doctor.com/element-index/#header) site and [w3 link](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-header-element).

as the doc says "An important point to note is that you are not restricted to using one  element per site. You can use multiple headers, each of which will then become the  for that section of the document. You could therefore have.".

```
<header>
    <h1>The most important heading on this page</h1>
    <p>With some supplementary information</p>
</header>

<article>
<header>
    <h1>Title of this article</h1>
    <p>By Richard Clark</p>
</header>
    <p>...Lorem Ipsum dolor set amet...</p>
</article>
```

For more information visit the site of [html5doctor](http://html5doctor.com/the-header-element/).

**According to your edit**

```
<footer>
  <section class="external-links">
   <img src="dummy.jpg">
   <h1>External Links</h1>
  </section>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what I really want to know is how am I supposed to put a `<section>` in the pages `<header>` (or `<footer>`) and giving it a heading?